# Custom Claims Proivder and People Picker SPException user does not exist or is not unique

Tags: 2010, adfs

I am trying to solve the following problem. We have a web app with multiple authentication methods (Windows, Forms and ADFS). With the usual ADFS deployment the People Picker will not resolve the names of users that login via ADFS. It will just accept any string that you type in.

In our environment we have a database table that stores all of the email address of the users regardless of the authentication method(Windows, Forms or ADFS).

I have created a Custom Claims Provider that searches the database and returns matching email addresses. I have deployed and the search works inside the People Picker. If we create a task and use the People Picker to assign the task it works correctly. However, if I try to add the user to a SharePoint group I get an SPException: The user does not exist or is not unique.

From the logs

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The user does not exist
>   or is not unique.    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.UpdateMembers(String
>   bstrUrl, UInt32 dwObjectType, String bstrObjId, Guid& pguidScopeId,
>   Int32 lGroupID, Int32 lGroupOwnerId, Object& pvarArrayAdd, Object&
>   pvarArrayAddIds, Object& pvarArrayLoginsRemove, Object&
>   pvarArrayIdsRemove, Boolean bRemoveFromCurrentScopeOnly, Boolean
>   bSendEmail)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.UpdateMembers(String bstrUrl,
>   UInt32 dwObjectType, String bstrObjId, Guid& pguidScopeId, Int32
>   lGroupID, Int32 lGroupOwnerId, Object& pvarArrayAdd, Object&
>   pvarArrayAddIds, Object& pvarArrayLoginsRemove, Object&
>   pvarArrayIdsRemove, Boolean bRemoveFromCurrentScopeOnly, Boolean
>   bSendEmail)

From the web page errors

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> 0x81020054stswel.dll: (unresolved
>   symbol, module offset=000000000013870F) at 0x000007FEEC88870F
>   stswel.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=000000000013E0D2) at
>   0x000007FEEC88E0D2 stswel.dll: (unresolved symbol, module
>   offset=000000000013EB4F) at 0x000007FEEC88EB4F owssvr.dll: (unresolved
>   symbol, module offset=00000000000AD8B0) at 0x000007FEE5E7D8B0
>   mscorwks.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000002CA3D7) at
>   0x000007FEF49AA3D7 Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.ni.dll: (unresolved
>   symbol, module offset=00000000000E4575) at 0x000007FEE7FC4575
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module
>   offset=0000000001AB1DD0) at 0x000007FEEA521DD0
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module
>   offset=0000000001B4E2E0) at 0x000007FEEA5BE2E0
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module
>   offset=0000000001B4E954) at 0x000007FEEA5BE954 The user
>   "c:05.f|vds|molly" does not exist and could not be added. All users
>   specified after "c:05.f|vds|molly" were also not added.  Description:
>   An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
>   0x81020054stswel.dll: (unresolved
>   symbol, module offset=000000000013870F) at 0x000007FEEC88870F
>   stswel.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=000000000013E0D2) at
>   0x000007FEEC88E0D2 stswel.dll: (unresolved symbol, module
>   offset=000000000013EB4F) at 0x000007FEEC88EB4F owssvr.dll: (unresolved
>   symbol, module offset=00000000000AD8B0) at 0x000007FEE5E7D8B0
>   mscorwks.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000002CA3D7) at
>   0x000007FEF49AA3D7 Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.ni.dll: (unresolved
>   symbol, module offset=00000000000E4575) at 0x000007FEE7FC4575
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module
>   offset=0000000001AB1DD0) at 0x000007FEEA521DD0
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module
>   offset=0000000001B4E2E0) at 0x000007FEEA5BE2E0
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module
>   offset=0000000001B4E954) at 0x000007FEEA5BE954 The user
>   "c:05.f|vds|molly" does not exist and could not be added. All users
>   specified after "c:05.f|vds|molly" were also not added.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [COMException (0x81020054):
>   0x81020054stswel.dll: (unresolved
>   symbol, module offset=000000000013870F) at 0x000007FEEC88870F
>   stswel.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=000000000013E0D2) at
>   0x000007FEEC88E0D2 stswel.dll: (unresolved symbol, module
>   offset=000000000013EB4F) at 0x000007FEEC88EB4F owssvr.dll: (unresolved
>   symbol, module offset=00000000000AD8B0) at 0x000007FEE5E7D8B0
>   mscorwks.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000002CA3D7) at
>   0x000007FEF49AA3D7 Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.ni.dll: (unresolved
>   symbol, module offset=00000000000E4575) at 0x000007FEE7FC4575
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module
>   offset=0000000001AB1DD0) at 0x000007FEEA521DD0
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module
>   offset=0000000001B4E2E0) at 0x000007FEEA5BE2E0
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module
>   offset=0000000001B4E954) at 0x000007FEEA5BE954 The user
>   "c:05.f|vds|molly" does not exist and could not be added. All users
>   specified after "c:05.f|vds|molly" were also not added.]
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.UpdateMembers(String
>   bstrUrl, UInt32 dwObjectType, String bstrObjId, Guid& pguidScopeId,
>   Int32 lGroupID, Int32 lGroupOwnerId, Object& pvarArrayAdd, Object&
>   pvarArrayAddIds, Object& pvarArrayLoginsRemove, Object&
>   pvarArrayIdsRemove, Boolean bRemoveFromCurrentScopeOnly, Boolean
>   bSendEmail) +0
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.UpdateMembers(String bstrUrl,
>   UInt32 dwObjectType, String bstrObjId, Guid& pguidScopeId, Int32
>   lGroupID, Int32 lGroupOwnerId, Object& pvarArrayAdd, Object&
>   pvarArrayAddIds, Object& pvarArrayLoginsRemove, Object&
>   pvarArrayIdsRemove, Boolean bRemoveFromCurrentScopeOnly, Boolean
>   bSendEmail) +240
>
> [SPException: The user "c:05.f|vds|molly" does not exist and could not
>   be added. All users specified after "c:05.f|vds|molly" were also not
>   added.]
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
>   +27601858    Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.UpdateMembers(String bstrUrl,
>   UInt32 dwObjectType, String bstrObjId, Guid& pguidScopeId, Int32
>   lGroupID, Int32 lGroupOwnerId, Object& pvarArrayAdd, Object&
>   pvarArrayAddIds, Object& pvarArrayLoginsRemove, Object&
>   pvarArrayIdsRemove, Boolean bRemoveFromCurrentScopeOnly, Boolean
>   bSendEmail) +27992950
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.UpdateMembers(Object
>   objUpdateInfo, Object objAddIds, Object objRemoveLogins, Object
>   objRemoveIds, Boolean fSendEmail) +560
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.AddCollection(SPUserInfo[]
>   addUsersInfo, IEnumerable`1 addUsers) +1060
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.AclInv.BtnOK_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +631
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +115
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +140
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +29
>
> ---

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Luis R. Lebron

Comment: I had this in my bookmarks but the link is dead! I believe the solution was to add the role for the custom provider in via powershell, I can't find this now though sorry, I hope it gives you a direction though.

Comment: Has the user you are trying to add successfully access the site? Even though the authentication works the user does not exist in SharePoint if they haven't logged in before.

Check the site's [users list](http://zimmergren.net/technical/sharepoints-hidden-user-list-user-information-list)

Comment: Onzur the users can login without any problems.